# Caching fonts on simple website to prevent FOIT?

Tags: php, html, css, performance, fonts

My website is incredibly slow, or at least the fonts are, and I am getting massive amounts of FOIT. I have solved this by putting a spinner on the frontpage, which does not display the website until the fonts are loaded. However, when I then visit other pages, I still get FOITs - how come? I thought the font was loaded now, and would not have to be loaded again?

If this is not the case, can i somehow cache it and save it, once its loaded?

I am using normal HTML, PHP, CSS.

Comment: If you give us the URL we can take a look and see why the fonts aren't caching.

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](https://www.afasterweb.com/2015/08/06/avoiding-the-foit/) which describes how to use a font face loader and monitor to avoid "Flashes Of Invisible Text" (FOIT.)

To answer specifically regarding caching of fonts once loaded: this should happen, so there may be one of the following issues occurring:

- Your server is not sending the appropriate cache control headers for the fonts resulting in them being re-requested on subsequent pages.
- Subsequent pages are referencing different font files or font files at different URLs than your main page.